# iOS13 access true depth camera data and dot cloud programmatically?

Tags: api, security, ios13, biometrics

I am interested in a research applications of the true depth camera used for iOS FaceID unlock.

I know that Apple already uses this data to animate the custom emoji.

**Is it possible to access the dot cloud data from the true depth camera programmatically?**

Answer (score 1):

I found out that you can, these lines represent the section that has to be investigated in order to get the result:

- [CVPixelBufferGetWidth(depthDataMap)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1457241-cvpixelbuffergetwidth)
- [CVPixelBufferGetHeight(depthDataMap)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1456666-cvpixelbuffergetheight)

Depth map also contains the values to be mathematically modified. Maybe u have found a different solution to this ? As i still have problems figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a few examples of using the ARKit. [One of the examples](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/additional_data_capture/streaming_depth_data_from_the_truedepth_camera) shows how to access the true depth camera (has a heat map mode).